# Prevent events bubbling up to an anchor using an onclick attribute

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I am building a widget that has clickable elements, and it is inserted into a `<a>` tag. I used every possible method to stopping a event, however, whenever the user clicks anything on the widget, the anchor's click handlers (both native, aka `href`, and `onclick`) are fired.

#### MCVE for both examples:

(`span` here portraying the widget)

```html
<a onclick="alert('fail evt')">
    event
    <span onclick="evt.preventDefault(); evt.stopPropagation(); evt.stopImmediatePropagation(); return false">
        potato
    </span>
</a>

<a href="javascript:alert('fail native');">
    native
    <span onclick="evt.preventDefault(); evt.stopPropagation(); evt.stopImmediatePropagation(); return false">
        potato
    </span>
</a>
```

For implementation reasons, it's not possible to use `addEventListener`. Unfortunately, the widget must have its handlers defined inline.

And yes, I know that you're not supposed to have clickable elements inside `<a>` tags.

Comment: It's not really valid to have clickable interactive content inside an `<a>` element.  What is it that you're trying to achieve? If it's OK to have a `<span>` be clickable inside, why not use a `<span>` instead of `<a>`?

Comment: @Pointy The `<a>` element is fixed in the layout, and I can only edit its contents.

Comment: Also, `evt` is never defined: `Uncaught ReferenceError: evt is not defined`

Comment: For these and others, I wish I could downvote my own posts. Please VTC as off-topic/typo

Answer (score 3):

You need to call `preventDefault`, and you need to do it on the `event` object, not the `undefined` `evt` object.

```html
<a href="javascript:alert('fail native');">
    native
           <span onclick="console.log('preventing prop'); event.preventDefault();">
        potato
    </span>
</a>
```

Comment: Heh, a classic "working for too long"-caused issue. Nothing like a fresh pair of eyes!